# New to Web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to teach myself some web scraping, just for fun. Decided to use it to look at a list of jobs posted on a website. I've gotten stuck. I want to be able to pull all the jobs listed on this page, but can't seem to get it to recognize anything deeper in the container I've made. Any suggestions are more than appreciated.

Current Code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

myURL = 'https://jobs.collinsaerospace.com/search-jobs/'

uClient = uReq(myURL)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
container = page_soup.findAll("section", {"id":"search-results-list"})
container
```

Sample of the container:

```
<section id="search-results-list">
 <ul>
 <li>
 <a data-job-id="12394447" href="/job/melbourne/test-technician/1738/12394447">
 <h2>Test Technician</h2>
 <span class="job-location">Melbourne, Florida</span>
 <span class="job-date-posted">06/27/2019</span>
 </a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a data-job-id="12394445" href="/job/cedar-rapids/associate-systems-engineer/1738/12394445">
 <h2>Associate Systems Engineer</h2>
 <span class="job-location">Cedar Rapids, Iowa</span>
 <span class="job-date-posted">06/27/2019</span>
 </a>
 </li>
 <li>
```

I'm trying to understand how to actually extract the h2 level information (or really any information within the container I currently created)

Comment: Can you help me understand why this is off topic?

Comment: Post (a sample of) the HTML you're trying to parse into your question. Tell us what data exactly you want to extract from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to replicate the same using lxml.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
resp = requests.get('https://jobs.collinsaerospace.com/search-jobs/')
data_root = html.fromstring(resp.content)

data = []
for node in data_root.xpath('//section[@id="search-results-list"]/ul/li'):
    data.append({"url":node.xpath('a/@href')[0],"name":node.xpath('a/h2/text()')[0],"location":node.xpath('a/span[@class="job-location"]/text()')[0],"posted":node.xpath('a/span[@class="job-date-posted"]/text()')[0]})
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you're looking to extract the headings from your `container`. Here's the snippet to do that:

```
for child in container:
    for heading in child.find_all('h2'):
        print(heading.text)
```

Note that `child` and `heading` are just dummy variables I'm using to iterate through the ResultSet (that the container is) and the list (that all the headings are). For each child, I'm searching for all the  tags, and for each one I'm printing its text.

If you wanted to extract something else from your container, just tweak `find_all`.